# Proper way to determine manufacturer/model of wireless card in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, asus, pci, lspci

What is the best way to find the manufacturer and model number of my wireless card?

Using the `lspci` and `lshw` commands I have determined that the manufacturer is Qualcomm Atheros and that the card is connected via pci, but I cannot determine the model number.  What is the best way to go about determining the model number of the network card?

EDIT 1:
The output of `lspci -nn | grep Net` is:

`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)`

So, is `[168c:0042]` the model number?

EDIT 2:
I now understand that the model number is unavailable if it has not been added 
to the kernel, and that `[168c:0042]` is the id number

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci -nn | grep Net` to your question. It should output the model name and the id.

Comment: This is the case when the kernel does not know the exact model yet. You probably are using the 4.4 kernel. But `[168c:0042]` is informative enough.

Comment: It is `QCA9377` in your case.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using the `4.4.0-78-generic` kernel. Can I ask how you determined the model number of `QCA9377`? Also, thank you very much.

Comment: I looked into the kernel source;-) But you can use google search by the id to find it yourself.

Comment: Also if it works, then you can find the model in `dmesg | grep ath10k` in your case. It loads firmware and outputs the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

This will output the exact card id and the driver in use.

This is an example (an old unused card in my desktop)

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:06.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] [168c:001a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: D-Link System Inc AirPlus G DWL-G510 Wireless PCI Adapter(rev.B) [1186:3a16]
    Kernel driver in use: ath5k
```

So the model name is `Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg]` and the id is `[168c:001a]`.

You can also see the vendor in the `Subsystem` section.

In some cases you can't see the exact model if it has not been added to the kernel sources, but the id is most important.

Your adapter model is `Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377`. Newer kernels know it.